# How can I pass a std::variant as a VARIANT* to ExecWB?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, code-analysis, variant

I have looked at this article about using [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant). This is because the following code was raising a code analysis warning:

```
void CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{
    if (nIDEvent == ID_TIMER_ZOOM)
    {
        //get the zoom value
        VARIANT vZoom{};
        vZoom.vt = VT_I4;
        vZoom.lVal = 0;
        ExecWB(OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, nullptr, &vZoom);
        TRACE("zoom %d\n", vZoom.lVal);

        //kill the timer
        KillTimer(nIDEvent);

        GetParent()->PostMessage(UWM_HTMLVIEW_CHANGE_ZOOM_MSG, vZoom.lVal);
        return;
    }

    CHtmlView::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
}
```

The warning:

> Warning [C26476](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26476?view=msvc-160): Expression/symbol `{{0, 0, 0, 0, {0}}}` uses a naked union 'union ' with multiple type pointers: Use `variant` instead (type.7).

I started to try and change the code:

```
void CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{
    if (nIDEvent == ID_TIMER_ZOOM)
    {
        //get the zoom value
        std::variant<long> vZoom(0);

        ExecWB(OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, nullptr, &vZoom);
        TRACE("zoom %d\n", vZoom.lVal);

        //kill the timer
        KillTimer(nIDEvent);

        GetParent()->PostMessage(UWM_HTMLVIEW_CHANGE_ZOOM_MSG, vZoom.lVal);
        return;
    }

    CHtmlView::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
}
```

But the problem is that `ExecWB` expects a `VARIANT *` and I do not see how to pass this `std::variant`.

Comment: Use `VARIANT vZoom; VariantInit(&vZoom);` to initialize. Or use `variant_t`, or `CComVariant` as suggested, they do this automatically.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Thanks - `VariantInit` - another new function I did not know!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The diagnostic is correct, even though the advice is too generic to be useful. While `std::variant` is, in general, a great way to represent typesafe [discriminated unions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union), it is unrelated to the [`VARIANT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/variant-structure) structure used in COM.

In this situation you would need to use a different type, such as Microsoft's [`_variant_t`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/variant-t-class) class. It encapsulates the raw `VARIANT`, and deals with the internals of its discriminated union.

It provides several constructors that properly manage setting the internal state, and derives from `VARIANT` so that any instance's address can be passed to any function that accepts a `VARIANT*`:

```cpp
#include <comutil.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "comsuppw.lib")

int main() {
    auto zoom{ _variant_t(long{ 0 }) };
    ExecWB(OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, nullptr, &zoom);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware of `variant_t`!

Comment: Microsoft provides a COM support library that consists of `_bstr_t`, `_com_error`, `_com_ptr`, and `_variant_t` that offer resource management and stronger type safety. That covers pretty much the entire type surface you'll see in COM programming. `_variant_t` is particularly useful due to the complex nature of the `VARIANT` structure.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry you can't use `std::variant` here.

`VARIANT` is a type used in COM for interoperation of different components, even if written in different languages and residing in different processes.

`std::variant` provides type-safe variant of arbitrary set of types that is passed as a template parameters. Even two `std::variant`s are incompatible if they have different template parameters, and none of them is compatible with `VARIANT`.

The best way you can make your program more robust is using `CComVariant` from ATL, or find/create another wrapper for `VARIANT` structure. Not sure if it would make the warning go away though.

Comment: Thanks. I have decided to go with `_variant_t` as suggested in the accepted answer.